# What is considered having in mind for other food items for the same bracha category?

Tags: halacha, blessing, eating, intent-accident-purposely

I don't know the exact source but all food items of the same category can be consumed after reciting a single bracha.

For example, if you have in mind to eat/drink tea, fish and ice cream you can say a single shehakol to cover all the items.

Is there a precise definition with all the criteria for "having in mind"?

If you usually have tea following a meal, but you don't have it in mind at the time of a bracha do you repeat the shehakol?

How about if you said a bracha in one room (living room) and began eating a separate item in a separate room (bed room) of the same house? Do you need to have in mind all the places you are going to eat?

Comment: I think "having in mind" *is* its own criteria. When you said the bracha, did you intend to eat this other food, or not?

Comment: Shokhet, it's not that simple - hence the question. Sometimes habitual practice is included in having in mind. Also other things may weigh in.

Comment: Habit, for example, comes in with a "שוחט דמתא," the "town shochet," whose "סתם דעת" is to shecht whatever comes in, so he only makes one bracha ([Simlah Chadasha 19:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=83)). I think the halacha, in the case of a person's habitual practice, follows whatever he had in mind. I'm not sure what "other things" you refer to.

Comment: http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur50.html